# Configure phpstorm for sourceforge as remote server

Tags: phpstorm, remote-server, sourceforge

I'm looking for configure my IDE phpstorm for connect to sourgeforge who contains my code. But I had a problem.
In window setting, Phpstorm ask me some informations :

Type of connexion (FTP/SFTP/FTPS) : I set SFTP
SFTP host : I set "mysourgeforgepseudo@frs.sourceforge.net"
Ports : 22 (automatically filled)
=> There is a button "Test SFTP connections..". When I push it, a popin notices me 'Successfully connected to "mysourgeforgepseudo@frs.sourceforge.net' ". So..its okay !

After..
Root path : /home/users/a/b/mysourgeforgepseudo/ (automatically filled)
Username : mysourgeforgepseudo
Auth type (Password or Key pair OpenSSH) : I set "Password"
Password : password in sourceforge..

And now, there is a field "Web server root URL". So, I set this line : (but maybe Im wrong ?) "https://mysourgeforgepseudo@git.code.sf.net/p/myproject/code"

When I click to the button "Next", Phpstorm check if settings are OK, but no..I get this message : "Connection to 'sourceforge' failed.
HEAD method failed for "https://mysourgeforgepseudo@git.code.sf.net/p/myproject/code" with HTTP status 401."

I don't understand..When I enter this url in my browser, I get a empty page (So, there is a problem!). But I get this URL from my personal space of the sourceforge webdite..Where is(are?) the mistake(s?) ?

Answer (score 0):

PHPstorm tries to reach your webserver with HEAD request, just to check response code. It gets 401, that is access denied. So once you set up webserver URL that works (response code 200) you'll be able to proceed.
In your particular case, it seems that you are trying to logi without password, which is unlikely to work.